# Pass an argument as a reference to get a JSON property

Tags: javascript, json, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm working on a facebook app with JS SDK...

I want to create a function that makes an API call to the Graph API:

This is what I got:

```
function a(reference){
    FB.api('/me', function(respond){            
         var it = respond.reference[0].name;
         alert(it);
    });
}
```

I try executing it this way but it doesn't work.

```
a("inspirational_people");
```

Comment: you are not using the `reference` parameter. How doesn't it work? Do other FB functions work?

Comment: Other FB functions work.  

 `function a(reference){FB.api('/me/'+reference, function(respond){var it = respond.data[0].name;alert(it);});}`

This works too. I think I should not simply pass an argument as a pointer that points to a property in a JSON object... But I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: What do you mean by "JSON objects" ?

Comment: JavaScript Object Notation objects. All responses returned by Graph API calls are JSON objects. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: To be strict, JSON is a notation in which object can be stored. I guess what you are talking about are simply ''objects''. I still do not understand why you are not using the `reference` parameter inside the `a` function. And no, it makes no difference if the value you are passing is a property in some object - in fact in a way all JS variables are pointers to a property of some object.

Comment: Oh.. I see. Thank you! I didn't actually learn programming the proper way. I started first on js. I learnt every bit of it from the Internet and I get the term "JSON objects" from [facebook] (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).. At first, I found the expression odd too, considering JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation, but then I thought that's what everybody calls it.

Comment: And now I understand what you actually mean by "not using the parameter".. I past the argument correctly but I should have written response[reference] to use the parameter properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you’re feeding the text string "inspirational_people" into your function, and you want to access a property of the response object having that very name?

That’s quite easy, basic JavaScript syntax: Every property that you can access via `object.propertyName` you can also access as `object["propertyName"]`.

So in your case, since you want to access `response.inspirational_people[0].name`, it’s `response[reference][0].name` – the actual string value of *reference* is evaluated at runtime, and you should end up having what you wanted.